# Maximum IIF Nesting reached VBA SQL

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, adodb

I have a sql script running in VBA with nested `IFF([col1-9] like '%something%, 'Something','other')` to search in 9 columns for a 10 different strings.

I have now reached the maximum complexity/references for the column and get an error. Is there a workaround to nest more IIF? Is there a better way entirely to find a value in multiple columns and return a value if found?

Comment: Is it in Access?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav ODADB connection in vba to a worksheet

Comment: Use SQL then, rather than loads of IF's etc.  See solution from Gordon, using switch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use nested `iif()` when you can use [`switch()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-function-d750c10d-0c8e-444c-9e63-f47504f9e379):

```
select switch(condition1, value1,
              condition2, value2,
              . . .
              1=1, <else value>
             )
```